# How to set unique theme for post and pages wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to setup different theme for wordpress post and pages.
I also found this type of question on stack but don't satisfied with answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution of my problem after made R&D on google.

For that I installed plugin called "Page Theme".
https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-theme/

Just install it an you can user different theme for post and pages of wordpress.
It will not work if your permalink is set as per post id so please change permalink to post name for that.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For Page, please read http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

And for custom post type, try to create a php file your_post_type-single.php and out it in your theme

e.g: you have a type of post called 'hello', then its name would be 'hello-single.php';
the format will be

```
get_header();
```

//your code//

```
 get_footer();
```